# Is it normal to set jar name as the beginning of the package names

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, osgi

The situation. I use osgi and I have java-ee server and standalone rmi client. And I have some module/component `testme`. So I have three bundles:

1. for server //testme.AClass, testme.ZClass
2. shared - contains ejb interface and DTO. //testMe.TClass,testme.BClass
3. client //testme.GClass, testme.KClass

In this situation there are three packages, which have classes about `testme` module. Of course every osgi bundle is a separate maven project.

The problem - when I have some error in log it's difficult to understand at what bundle the class is located. So, maybe should I define the name of the jar as the beginning of the package. I mean should I name these 3 jar files like this: `com.example.svr,com.example.shd,com.example.clt` and the full name of classes would be like `com.example.svr.testme.AClass`. Using such naming approach I always understand from logs what osgi bundle - maven project has problems. However I don't see such practise using foreign libs. Is it normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is getting more and more popular to add "fully qualified" name for the jars. You can find many examples about it.

E.g.:

- The core OSGi jar is not called just "core" but "osgi.core".
- See the [artifact names](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.felix%22) under the Apache Felix project
- See the [artifact names](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Capache%20aries) under the Apache Aries project

I would not say that the name of the JAR should be the same as the name of the package it contains as it would raise too many questions. E.g.: What if there are multiple exported packages in the JAR file?

I would say that the jar name should contain not only the simple name of the project but the namespace as well, preferably in the same format as java packages have.